# Como montar um array dinamicamente

Tags: array, swift, swift-3

Gostaria de fazer uma **func** que me retornasse o array que segue, contudo não sei o tipo do retorno nem como montar, dinamicamente, este array:

```
vDataSource_Detalhe = NSArray(objects:
    NSArray(objects: "Cerveja 01","Cerveja 02"),
    NSArray(objects : "Refrigerante 01","Refrigerante 02","Refrigerante 03"),
    NSArray(objects : "Guarana 01","Guarana 02","Guarana 03","Gurana 04"),
    NSArray(objects : "Guaravita 01"),
    NSArray(objects : "Caipirinha 01","Caipirinha 02","Caipirinha 03"),
    NSArray(objects : "Coca-Cola 0'","Coca-Cola 02","Coca-Cola 03"),
    NSArray(objects : "Pepsi 01","Pepsi 02")
)
```

Gostaria que o esqueleto da func ficasse assim :

```
func retorna(_ pQtd_Linhas : Int)-> ???????  /* 01 - como deve ficar estas interrogaçoes*/
{
    let vResultado = ???????();  /*02 como deve ficar estas interrogaçoes*/
    var vLinha : ??????;  /*03 como deve ficar estas interrogaçoes*/
    for A in 0...pQtdLinhas - 1
    {
        vLinha = ?????; /*04 como deve ficar estas interrogaçoes*/
        let C = Gerar_Qtd_Randomica();
        for B in 1...C
        {
            vItem = ????();  /*05 como deve ficar estas interrogaçoes*/
            vItem.append(Gerar_nome_randomico());
            vLinha.append(vItem)  /* é append mesmo??*/

        }
        vResultado.append(vLinha); /* é append mesmo??*/
    }
    return vResultado;
}
```

Comment: Seria algo assim: `anArray += ["a", "b", "c"]
anArray.append(contentsOf: ["a", "b", "c"])`
`, mas [veja aqui](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126937-append)

Comment: [Aqui tem mais](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) sobre array.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, acho que depende. Você pode colocar no retorno `[Any]`, que vai servir pra array de qualquer coisa. MAS não sei se isso é o que você precisa.

Pelo seu código, me parece que você precisa simplesmente de um array bidimensional de String, não? Nesse caso, o que você precisa retornar é `[[String]]` e o seu vDataSource_Detalhe pode ser:

```
vDataSource_Detalhe = [["Cerveja 01","Cerveja 02"], 
     ["Refrigerante 01","Refrigerante 02","Refrigerante 03"],
     ["Guarana 01","Guarana 02","Guarana 03","Gurana 04"],
     ["Guaravita 01"],
     ["Caipirinha 01","Caipirinha 02","Caipirinha 03"],
     ["Coca-Cola 0'","Coca-Cola 02","Coca-Cola 03"],
     ["Pepsi 01","Pepsi 02"]]
```

Comment: Boa noite, Ricardo.

Comment: Boa noite Andreza.. 
Quero implementar um pickerview tipo ""Estado-> Cidade"" 
para usar na func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int 
e 
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? .
Para as cidades estou tendo problema. So consegui fazer funcionar montando o array ESTATICAMENTE da forma
como demonstrei primeiramente. Quando clicar no estado RJ quero setar as cidades do mesmo.
Com o Array Bidimensional como você falou eu não consegui usa-lo nas duas funções corretamente.

Comment: Nesse caso, como você só vai carregar a cidade depois que selecionar o estado, eu entendo que o que você precisa são dois arrays: um para estado e outro para cidades. O de estado você já preenche com todos os estados. O das cidades você vai deixar vazio (não nil, mas vazio) até o usuário selecionar o estado. Quando ele selecionar, você preenche esse array e manda o pickerView fazer o reload para ele usar as funções de delegate (numberOfRows e titleForRow). Já tentou isso?

Comment: Bom dia Andreza..Então.. Quando eu monto o primeiro item do array ESTADO, quero montar o ARRAY vDataSource_Detalhe.. e essa é minha pergunta... **COMO MONTA-LO dinamicamente** na estrutura que passei : **vDataSource_Detalhe = NSArray(objects:
    NSArray(objects: "Cerveja 01","Cerveja 02"),** etc....    Assim quando do lado ESQUERDO (estado) do pickerview  estiver selecionado RJ do lado DIREITO estarão todas as cidades dele. As funções de delegate eu sei usa-las .. o problema realmente é montar o array dessa forma.. Estaticamente funciona. só que os estados e cidades vem na base. abraços.. :)

Comment: O que você quer dizer por "dinamicamente" é simplesmente atualizar o array de cidade quando selecionar o valor de estado?

Comment: **A lógica que imaginei** para a viewcontroler em questão é: Ao entra consulto somente uma vez a base e carrego todos os arrays. **Dinamicamente**..: A func que demonstro no inicio montaria **DINAMICAMENTE** o array ... Mas eu NÃO sei os valores que estão nos pontos de interrogação.

Comment: Ricardo, desculpa, mas eu não entendo isso como array dinâmico. Se os valores são sempre fixos, o array é estático. MAS, como eu disse na resposta, você pode retornar [Any] que serve pra qualquer coisa. Já tentou fazer isso?

Comment: Boa noite.. :) Minha questão é simples... : Montar uma função que retorne EXATAMENTE aquele TIPO de array..  Eu consigo fazer funções me retornando [Any]... [Classe_Tal]... [[xxx]]... Array<yyyy>.. ETC..Eu só quero saber como fazer uma função retornar AQUELA ESTRUTURA INICIAL. abraços.